# Discord bot won't answer unless specifically mentioned

Tags: python, discord

Let me start with acknowledging that I am very new to coding and my question might be 'dumb'. I attempted to code a Discord bot with the simple instruction to reply to a message if the original message contains the word 'congrats'. The bot is operational, but only replies when it is specifically mentioned in the original message.

So 'congrats @bot' returns a message from the bot, but purely 'congrats' does not get a response. I'll present the code below:

```
import discord

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
intents.guild_messages = True
intents.reactions = True

client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
   print('Message received:', message.content)

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    print('Message received:', message.content)

    if message.author == client.user:
        print(f"Message content: {message.content}")
        return

    if "congrats" in message.content.lower():
        await message.channel.send("Jinx!)
        print(message.channel)

client.run('TOKEN')
```

I added the print lines to see whether the code is actually triggered at all. If the bot is not mentioned explicitly, it returns 'message received: '. I tried to find out whether it is a permissions issue, but when I add the following line to the if block, it reacts to whichever message (so then it would not be a permissions issue right?...)

```
else:
  await message.channel.send("XXX")
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You need the Message Content intent enabled. Discord now only gives you access to the message content if your bot is specifically mentioned, unless you have that privileged intent enabled. It should be inside your bot's dashboard.

Notice the one on the bottom:

[image: List of privileged gateway intents; Message Content is on the bottom]

Also, ensure you have done `intents.message_content = True`, as per [Discord.py API docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=intents#discord.Intents.message_content) (`guild_messages` is not enough)

Comment: Thank you for the swift reply! The message content intent (and all others) have been enabled.

Comment: @FHh Have you tried doing `intents.message_content = True`? `guild_messages` is not enough to get it working, as per [Discord.py API docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=intents#discord.Intents.message_content).